# Hide iPad mail icon without jailbreaking

Tags: ios, ipad, email

I need a way to hide the mail icon on an iPad as my business the emails need to be secured. I know you can jailbreak the device and achieve it but this is not viable for me.

Answer (score -2):

You can use restrictions in settings, but if you do you cannot access mail without re-enabling it.
To enable restrictions go to settings, general, restrictions and tap on enable restrictions.

Comment: You can't restrict Mail using iOS restrictions…?